# Reading Gsheet using Pandas with authentication

Tags: pandas, google-sheets, pyspark, databricks

I want to read a gsheet using pandas in databricks.

```
gsheet_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<Sheetid>/export?gid=0&format=csv'
df = df = pd.read_csv(gsheet_url,index_col=0)
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

The code works fine when the Google sheet is shared publically, but when the shared sheet is restricted within a group i get error

```
Error tokenizing data.C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 2
```

How do i read gsheet with authentication ?

Comment: If you want to use credentials and Google API features, please consider using `googleapiclient` python package (docs [here](https://pypi.org/project/google-api-python-client/)).

Comment: there's no direct way to achieve this in pandas?